# How can I change the theme (red) color of PowerPoint for Mac?

Tags: ms-office

[image]

For example in the picture, the theme color of the PowerPoint is red. How can I change it to e.g. black/blue? There is no option in MS Office to do this, but how about Mac system?

Answer (score 1):

> There is no option in MS Office to do this, but how about Mac system?

There is no built-in option in macOS to theme/visually style apps. The most you can do is to turn on Dark Mode by going to System Preferences → General and select Dark for Appearance (1st item at the top). This way, you can get dark grey appearance in PowerPoint for macOS.

Office for Mac version 16.20, Office 365 and Office 2019 support Dark Mode on macOS Mojave. From this linked article on MacRumors:

- [Microsoft Office Apps Now Support Dark Mode on macOS Mojave](https://www.macrumors.com/2018/12/11/microsoft-office-dark-mode-mac-mojave/)

> Microsoft today updated its suite of Office for Mac apps, including Word, Excel, PowerPoint, and Outlook, with support for Dark Mode on macOS Mojave and several other new features. The updates are available to both Office 365 subscribers and to users who purchased Office 2019 for Mac as a one-time purchase.
>
> [image]

and

- [November 2018 release](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/release-notes-office-for-mac#november-2018-release)

> #### Microsoft Auto Update 4.5
>
> - Support for Dark Mode

and

- https://twitter.com/derek_snook/status/1072614131730169858

> And with v16.20 some customers will see our Ribbon Visual Refresh with new icons and styling in Office 365 for Mac, as we begin rolling out and getting your feedback! On macOS Mojave, the new icons adapt to Light and Dark Mode as well!  #Office365
>
> [image] [image]

To learn more about Dark Mode, refer to the Apple Support article:

- [How to use Dark Mode on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208976)

Answer (score 0):

You have the choice of two whole themes in Office 2016 for the Mac (two, wow!).

Unlike Office for PC you don't have much selection in what color themes Office uses.

`Powerpoint > Preferences > General > Personalize, Office Theme > Classic/Colorful`

As far as I am aware that is the only way to change the MS Office interface colors. Note that any changes you make in any Office app change *all of the Office apps.*

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for 2019 version. I don't have office theme under personalize (under word/excel). For powerpoint, there is not even an option of Personalize. Is Office Theme located at different location in 2019 version?

Comment: Crap! sorry. I just love it when MS removes features, especially when they exist in the Windows version.